# Best way to display dynamic data in a webpage

Tags: activemq-classic, real-time, visualization

My goal is to visualize the incoming data stream on a browser. I have used activemq to queue the stream. A single message consumed from the queue looks like this: "int,date/time,int,string". I have to update my line graph on the browser (every 100ms). Any ideas?

Comment: Was hoping to get help here. Guess this isn't the place. Thanks for the support guys. cheers and happy coding!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a use case for [WebSocket](http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html).

There are many ways to implement it, but a rather nice blog post on the topic is presented [here](http://cmoulliard.blogspot.se/2012/04/real-time-html5-application-with.html).

Another way is to use [MQTT](http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt) [directly from the browser](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-web-client) using javascript and subscribe to a topic with your updates. You have to forward your data to that topic, in this case. For that, you can use [composite queues](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) with `forwardOnly=false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Petter!! The thing about using raw sockets is that I am concerned about packet loss occurring during a session. That's the reason I used activemq. U actually opened my eyes lol. I was using a queue which was incorrect in my case. Gonna change it immediately. Your second method sounds promising. Will try that out also and I'll let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ActiveMQ, you could enable its websockets interface:  http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html

In your browser code, use the STOMP over WebSocket library to subscribe to the queue.  http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/