# How is the correct way to receive messages using MQTT (paho) + activeMQ?

Tags: java, javascript, activemq-classic, mqtt, paho

I have a Java Swing application that uses activeMQ 5.9.1 with topics and queues.

Now, my intention is to migrate that swing application to web, so I'm making some proves using activeMQ + MQTT (paho) javascript library.

I have enabled that in activemq.xml:

```
<transportConnector name="mqtt+ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.defaultKeepAlive=30000"/>
```

And I have implemented some examples with MQTT (paho - http://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) for listening some topics.

```
function ramdomID(length) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}

var client = new Messaging.Client('192.168.240.17', 1883, ramdomID(20));

client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});

function onConnect() {
    console.log("onConnect");
    client.subscribe("/KeepAlive");
}

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        console.log("onConnectionLost: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
}

function onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived: "+message.payloadString);
}
```

The responses to a topic are received correctly, but the recovered message is a Java String object reference:

```
onMessageArrived: ﭭsr<com.my.project.bp.jms.MyImplementedMessageLmessagetLjava/lang/String;Ltypeq~xppt  KeepAlivey
```

Anyone knows the correct way to receive a friendly message if a java application writes on activeMQ topic directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go from ActiveMQ to a browser, take a look at enabling just Websockets within ActiveMQ and using the STOMP over Websockets javascript library.  The body of the message will be a friendly text object.  The links are at my answer here:  [Best way to display dynamic data in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654715/best-way-to-display-dynamic-data-in-a-webpage/24196161#24196161)

Comment: Thanks for response. But i'm using MQTT over Websockets. I found my error: on server side, I have some functions using JMS and they were using javax.jms.ObjectMessage object for writing a Topic. Changing that object to javax.jms.TextMessage and setting the message in JSON all works fine!